# Check if OP_ACCEPT-ed Selection key has waiting connection to open

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Consider that I've use selectors to handle user connections:

Initialization:

```
this.channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();

this.channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(4321));
this.channel.configureBlocking(false);

this.selector = Selector.open();
this.channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

Main loop:

```
while (this.channel.isOpen()) {
    selector.select();
    for (SelectionKey key : this.selector.selectedKeys()) {
        if (key.isAcceptable()) this.acceptNewConnection(key);
        else if (key.isReadable()) this.readFromConnection(key); 
    }
}
```

Accepting connection:

```
private void acceptNewConnection(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    final SocketChannel channel = SelectionKeyHelpers.getServerSocketChannel(key).accept();
    final String address = SocketHelpers.getConnectorAddres(channel.socket());

    channel.configureBlocking(false);
    channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, address);
}
```

Eveything works almost fine... First connection is accepted and new selection key is added (with `OP_READ`).

The problem is that when some data is ready to read, `selectedKeys()` returns collection with two selection keys: the one to read and other with `OP_OPEN` despite there is no connection to access (in this case `isAcceptable` returns also true). So, getting socket from that SelectionKey (in acceptNewConncetion) returns `null`.

So.. is there any way to exclude selection key with `OP_OPEN` from `selectedKeys()` when there is no new connection available?

Is checking wheter socket channel == `null` is enough or there is more appropriate way? f.e:

```
final SocketChannel channel = SelectionKeyHelpers.getServerSocketChannel(key).accept();
if (channel == null) {
    // key is selected but there is nothing to accept
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no such thing as OP_OPEN.
2. The problem here is a bug in your code. You need to remove each processed key from the selected key set. The selector never does that.

Comment: Ok, I meant `OP_ACCEPT`.. When I remove accepted key, no new connection are accepted. Should I add new key again for accepting? Or you mean to remove key directly from selectedKey set without cancelling it?

Comment: That's not only what I meant, it is what I said. I didn't say a word about cancelling anything.